# Can I replace SLAB one-method-per-event with types?

Tags: c#, logging, slab

[Examples for SLAB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440729(v=pandp.60).aspx) tend to look like this:

```
MyCompanyEventSource.Log.ScalingRequestSubmitted(
    request.RoleName, 
    request.InstanceCount,
    context.RuleName,
    context.CurrentInstanceCount);
```

I don't like that I have to edit `MyCompanyEventSource` every time I add a new event type. I also don't like that the logger is only available staticly. I'd rather have something like this:

```
_logger.Log(new ScalingRequestSubmittedEvent(request, context));
```

I know I can just roll my own logging, but before I dismiss SLAB entirely, I'd like to know if I'm being unfair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do things like this

```
_logger.Log(new ScalingRequestSubmittedEvent(request, context));
```

And you have to change your logger any time you wish to add a new type of event, change information level or keyword.

Writing of your own wrapper for EventSource is the only way to achieve desired functionality.